# Import file in Python (numpy) as contiguous memory array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to import data from a text file, and read it in as a contiguous memory array. This is the data, with every respondent separated by a return:

`['vrouw', 43, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']`

`['vrouw', 34, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']`

`['vrouw', 32, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']`

`['vrouw', 32, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']`

`['vrouw', 43, '3', 'sport', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']`

`['vrouw', 32, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']`

`['vrouw', 43, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '3', '3', 'collega', 'nee']`

I tried to use the following code to import the data from the text file:

```
vragenlijst_data= np.genfromtxt('antwoorden.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=('geslacht', 'leeftijd', 'stelling1', 'doorvraag1', 'stelling2', 'stelling3', 'doorvraag3', 'opmerking'))
```

However, this way I can't use the np.mean (from the numpy library) in a vectorised way, because I have no contiguous memory array. Does anyone know a way to read the data so that I have a contiguous memory array (preferrably with numpy)?

Comment: You can't use `np.mean` since you have a `dtype=object` array with strings. Or what output do you expect from using `np.mean` on a `str`?

Comment: you want to use np.mean on all numeric columns or just leeftijd?

Comment: I only want to use np.mean on the column 'leeftijd'

Comment: Describe the results of the genfrom test . shaoe, dtype  etc.  The  brackets and quotes make reading that file messy.  Also what kind of mean do you want?

Comment: The result of genfromtxt is: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>. I want to calculate a mean value for 'leeftijd' in numpy. The code 'mean = np.mean([int(i[1]) for i in vragenlijst_data])' works, but I want to use np.mean in a vectorised way, so that I can use np.mean(vragenlijst_data[1])

Comment: I know it produces an `ndarray`.  You need to tell us about that array - properties like `shape` and `dtype`.  `dtype` is not `type`.  I suspect you have a structured array.  With a mix of strings and numbers you can't have a simple numeric array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a copy-n-paste of your lines:

```
In [362]: txt
Out[362]: "['vrouw', 43, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']\n\n['vrouw', 34, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']\n\n['vrouw', 32, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']\n\n['vrouw', 32, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']\n\n['vrouw', 43, '3', 'sport', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']\n\n['vrouw', 32, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '2', '2', 'onbeantwoord', '']\n\n['vrouw', 43, '2', 'onbeantwoord', '3', '3', 'collega', 'nee']"

In [364]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',dtype=None, encoding=None)
In [365]: data
Out[365]: 
array([("['vrouw'", 43, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
       ("['vrouw'", 34, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
       ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
       ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
       ("['vrouw'", 43, " '3'", " 'sport'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
       ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
       ("['vrouw'", 43, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '3'", " '3'", " 'collega'", " 'nee']")],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U4'), ('f3', '<U15'), ('f4', '<U4'), ('f5', '<U4'), ('f6', '<U15'), ('f7', '<U7')])
```

The result is a 1d structured array with a mix of string and numeric fields, which have to be referenced by name, not column number.

'f1' is numeric, because it doesn't have quotes in the in original.  So can view that field, and easily take its mean:

```
In [367]: data['f1']
Out[367]: array([43, 34, 32, 32, 43, 32, 43])
In [368]: np.mean(data['f1'])
Out[368]: 37.0
```

`genfromtxt` doesn't remove brackets, so the 'f0' strings still have them.

The extra layer of quotes also makes it harder to convert the other fields to integer.

If the file had cleaner csv values it would be easier to read and use:

```
In [372]: txt1 = """vrouw, 43, 2, onbeantwoord, 2, 2, onbeantwoord, ''
     ...: vrouw, 34, 2, onbeantwoord, 2, 2, onbeantwoord, '' """
     ...: 
In [373]: 
In [373]: data1 = np.genfromtxt(txt1.splitlines(), delimiter=',',dtype=None, enc
     ...: oding=None)
In [374]: data1
Out[374]: 
array([('vrouw', 43, 2, ' onbeantwoord', 2, 2, ' onbeantwoord', " ''"),
       ('vrouw', 34, 2, ' onbeantwoord', 2, 2, ' onbeantwoord', " ''")],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<U13'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8'), ('f6', '<U13'), ('f7', '<U3')])
In [375]: data1['f0']
Out[375]: array(['vrouw', 'vrouw'], dtype='<U5')
In [376]: data1['f1']
Out[376]: array([43, 34])
In [377]: data1['f5']
Out[377]: array([2, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is malformed, looks like it's just the output of `print`. i don't think you'll find any library function to make your data usable (gentext builds an array with malformed data). so here goes:

```
import re

with open('antwoorden.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

vragenlijst = []
for line in lines:
    line = re.sub("[',\[\]]", '', line.strip())
    line = [x for x in line.split()]
    if len(line)==7:
        line += ['']
    vragenlijst.append(tuple(line))
```

vragenlijst is now a python list of 8-tuples, where each member is a string. tuples are necessary for numpy's structured arrays. so now you build your dtype like this:

```
vragenlijst_dtype = np.dtype([('geslacht', 'U10'), ('leeftijd', 'i4'), 
        ('stelling1', 'U10'), ('doorvraag1', 'U10'), ('stelling2', 'U10'), 
        ('stelling3', 'U10'), ('doorvraag3', 'U10'), ('opmerking', 'U10')])
```

where "U10" means unicode 10 characters long, and i4 an integer 4 bytes long. you can change the types if they don't fit to your real data.

and then:

```
vragenlijst = np.array(vragenlijst, dtype=vragenlijst_dtype)
list_mean = np.mean(vragenlijst['leeftijd'])
```

which outputs "37.0"